# SSRS Report Viewer Unable to Pass Credentials to Report Server from Hyperlink

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have a 3-rd party (like a portal) hosting our SSRS Report Viewer inside an iFrame.  The source of the iFrame is an ASP.NET web form page with the Report Viewer control.  We pass the credentials to the Report Viewer from the code behind and everything works fine.  Reports render in the viewer and the aspx page is running on an HTTPS site.

The report developer placed a hyperlink on a report that opens an non-HTTP url to the Report Sever that is supposed to download an Excel file.  But the Report Server is behind a DMZ (actually running as a Windows Service and not IIS) and prompts users for credentials and only downloads the Excel file when the Report Server credentials (same ones used by the Report Viewer) are entered.  This sounds like a double-hop issue.

Anybody trying to browse to the URL manually also get a prompt until they are authenticated because the SSRS is not in our domain.

**TL;DR;**

Is there anyway to pass the credentials of the Report Server from within a hyperlink inside the Report Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Functions as designed.  Reports Developer did not really understand implementation details and found a work around.